# CD not working in batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Creating a batch file to replace a file but I cannot get the command working.

The command: `cd "C:\Program Files\example_folder\"`

This command works from the command line but not when I run the script.

Script is saved as `test.bat` and I run it on an admin powershell window with `test.bat` from the directory the file is in.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Powershell uses `.ps1` scripts. `.bat` files are for command-line (`cmd.exe`) only. If you execute a `.bat` file a new cmd.exe instance is created, changes the directory and then ends and you come pack to powershell where nothing has changed.

Comment: Why do you run the batch file form a powershell script? If you want to run the batch file as administrator you can perform a powershell command to elevate from inside the batch file.

Comment: I can only guess that you need `cd /d "<path>"`.  Just because you "run it from there".. your startup directory is probably elsewhere (because of the problem you describe).  This is only a guess.. but probably a correct one.  Try echo'ing %CD% and adding a pause right after the call to figure out where your batch is at.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the batch file as administrator:

```
@echo off
net session >nul 2>&1 || (powershell start -verb runas '"%~0"' &exit /b)

cd "C:\Program Files\example_folder"

:: next command
:: next command
```